# Failed opening required '/composer/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

Tags: wamp, symfony-3.4

Suddenly i got this warning and error:

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/composer/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

I work on wamp server and use framework: Symfony3.4

I can't open my aplications and even localhost report these messages.

Does somedy know what could cause these problems?

Comment: **Suddenly??** Do you mean it was working and now it is not?

Comment: Yes, everything was ok. It's weird. Isn't it?

Comment: Do you have any idea what could happen?